# Try to create random json for firebase with json generator without success

Tags: json, generator

I try to build a json for me to test my firebase application. I need a couple of hundred entries and for that reason try to build me json with the JSON Generator from https://www.json-generator.com/

How ever I have problems to get random IDs as keys (and not as values). I tried all I can think of with **{{objectId()}}** but this seem to work only for values.

Does anybody have an idea how I could build a RANDOM JSON like the example below with the JSON Generator I used or any other generator? Again the problem is the random KEYS! As values this works great.

here an example of the JSON i need at the end.

```
{
  "-f2zawhcNgh6vcHIQOCq" : {
    "cat_id" : 1,
    "created_at" : 1516206514529,
    "edited_at" : 1516206514529,
    "groups" : {
      "-L2zawhcNgh6vcHIQOCq" : true,
      "-L2zaxyBs-9AfQJii47k" : true
    },
    "local" : true,
    "owner_id" : "MyaNhS4Qy6foMYkSIt0tpRQFneI3",
    "private" : false
  },
    "-fghgajhgfkjhkQOCq" : {
    "cat_id" : 1,
    "created_at" : 1516206514529,
    "edited_at" : 1516206514529,
    "groups" : {
      "-L2zawkjhfkjhkjgQOCq" : true
    },
    "local" : true,
    "owner_id" : "hgfjhYkSIt0tpRQFneI3",
    "private" : false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
JSON.stringify(new Array(200).fill('something').reduce(mock => {
mock[Math.random()] = {
    "cat_id" : 1,
    "created_at" : Date.now()*Math.random() | 0,
    "edited_at" : Date.now(),
    "groups" : {
      [Math.random()] : true
    },
    "local" : true,
    "owner_id" : Math.random(),
    "private" : false  
}
return mock
}, {}), undefined, 2)
```

Paste this in chrome js console or node.js
Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: This is a perfect solution for me. I just tweak a little bit but this is a great solution in deed. Thank you. I am going to take this snippet and do my own json-generator.js with it so I can use it always with some different json needs.